# How to Put ProgressBar in Button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, progress-bar

I am a newbie at WPF and did not pull off my attempt at putting a progressbar in a button. My previous question asked is at : [StackOverflow Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388333/accessing-progressbar-within-controltemplate-of-button). Any help with how to properly do this would be appreciated. I did not see another post on StackOverflow to address this. Ideally, it would be great to have the button (1) with text centered vertically (i.e. as appears normally in a button) and (2) with the progress bar below the text. The button would be 2 times default height to allow space for the progressbar. I can tweak position and spacing of anything you come up with. I am very interested in getting the bindings done correctly to update the progressbar.

Thanks!
Buck

Comment: override its template property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options, either create a `UserControl` or a new style for your button and override the `ControlTemplate`. I would recommend that you style `Button` since its easier and you don't end up creating a new type. Here's how you would do that.

```
<Button>
    <Button.Style>
        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <!-- Put in your textbox and progress bar and what not -->
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>   
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

You can read more about templating controls [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084.aspx) and can find the default `Style` and `ControlTemplate` for `Button` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

You can easily put any control in the `Content` property of the button:

```
<Button>
   <Button.Content>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
            <TextBlock Text="I'm a button with progress bar!"></TextBlock>
            <ProgressBar Height="20"></ProgressBar>
         </StackPanel>
   </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

This will result in a button control like this:

[image]

If you need more than one, you should declare a `Style` and apply that to the buttons in the form, as others suggested.

Answer (score 4):

Use Mah app

```
<Button Canvas.Left="170"
                                Canvas.Top="71"
                                Width="55"
                                Command="{Binding SearchEmployeeCommand}">
                            <Canvas Width="50" Height="20">
                                <TextBlock Text="select ..." />
                                <controls:ProgressRing Canvas.Left="15"
                                                       Width="20"
                                                       Height="20"
                                                       IsActive="True"
                                                       Visibility="Visible" />
                            </Canvas>
                        </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a single instance of this you could do something like this:

```
<Button Click="Button_Click_1">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World"/>
            <ProgressBar Height="10" x:Name="pb1" Maximum="15"></ProgressBar>
        </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Then in your C# code you could access the progress bar such as:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pb1.Value++;
}
```